# Include Function File in function.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started using wordpress.

I created this function inside function.php, and include file below, works!:

```
function is_live_2020() {
  if(is_page_template('landing.php') || is_page_template('collection.php')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

include get_template_directory().'/model-filter.php';
```

but when I created new function again, include file doesn't work:

```
function is_staging() {
    if(is_page_template('landing-staging.php') || is_page_template('collection-staging.php')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

function load_model_filter() {
    if (is_live_2020()) {
        include get_template_directory().'/model-filter.php';
    } else {
        include get_template_directory().'/model-filter-new.php';
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'load_model_filter');
```

how is the correct way to include those function files?

btw.. here model-filter.php:

```
<?php 
function collectionFilter() {

    global $wpdb;

    $where = array();

    if (location_slug()=='my') {
        if (1 == $_POST['fman'] && 0 == $_POST['fwoman']) {
        $where[] = "filter_Gender like '".(_x_filter_strings($_POST['en'],"men"))."%'";
        } else if (0 == $_POST['fman'] && 1 == $_POST['fwoman']) {
            $where[] = "filter_Gender like '%".(_x_filter_strings($_POST['en'],"women"))."'";
        }
    
        $size = array();
    
        if (1 == $_POST['f28']) {
            $size[] = (_x_filter_strings($_POST['en'],"small_size"));
        }
    
        if (1 == $_POST['f36']) {
            $size[] = (_x_filter_strings($_POST['en'],"mid_size"));
        }
    
        if (1 == $_POST['f40']) {
            $size[] = (_x_filter_strings($_POST['en'],"large_size"));
        }
    
        if (0 < count($size)) {
            $where[] = "filter_Size IN ('" . implode("', '", $size) . "')";

etc.....
```

Comment: When you say "include file doesn't work", do you mean that it isn't included or do you get an error trying to include it? Is `get_template_directory().'/model-filter.php' the correct page (i.e. does it exist directly in the theme folder and not in a subfolder?).  Also, have co confirmed if it *is* getting included but the code isn't being executed?

Comment: @FluffyKitten sorry, I maent there is error (“There has been a critical error on your website”). yes, get_template_directory().'/model-filter.php is the correct page.. it works without conditional function..

Comment: That error usually means there is an error in your syntax somewhere. It could be in functions.php but its quite likely to be in the file you're including too. You'll need to debug the code to track that down and fix it, then it should work.